# asp.net oracle database 3 tier cannot convert string to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm working in Asp.net C# 3 tier with oracle database. I create a function for Read and Delete and it is working but for the insert and update I’m getting error of converting string to datetime.

Here is the Business layer code:

```
        public void InsertSurvey(string SURV_NAME, DateTime SURV_STARTDATE, DateTime S_ENDDATE)
    {

        try
        {
            string str = "select max(SURV_ID) as max_SURV_ID from SURVEY";
            int maxVal = (_dbAccess.returnint32(str));
            string SURV_ID = Convert.ToString(maxVal);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SURV_ID))
            {
                maxVal = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                maxVal++;

            }

            string strInsert = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT SURVEY ON insert into SURVEY(SURV_ID,SURV_NAME,SURV_STARTDATE,S_ENDDATE) values('" + maxVal + "','" + SURV_NAME + "','" + SURV_STARTDATE + "','" + S_ENDDATE + "') SET IDENTITY_INSERT SURVEY OFF";
            _dbAccess.executeQuery(strInsert);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

And here is the Submit code from the page code behind for the insert form:

```
    public partial class Survey_insert_survey : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    BusSurvey _objSurvey = new BusSurvey();
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _objSurvey.InsertSurvey(txtSURV_NAME.Text, txtSURV_STARTDATE.Text, txtS_ENDDATE.Text);
        //If records successfully entered then redirect to feedback page
        Response.Redirect("view-survey.aspx");

    }
}
```

This the error Im getteing:

[image]

Hope I get help

Answer (score 1):

At InsertSurvey method you are expecting a DateTime as an argument and you are trying to pass string (inserted from textbox).

```
_objSurvey.InsertSurvey(txtSURV_NAME.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(txtSURV_STARTDATE.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(txtS_ENDDATE.Text));
```

You can try this as well.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtf = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
String sDate = txtSURV_STARTDATE.text;
dtf.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
dtf.DateSeparator = "-";
DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sDate, dtf);
```

Comment: I tried but it gave me error `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException was unhandled by user code
  Message=ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
  Source=App_Code._rfz6rdu
  ErrorCode=-2146232008
  Code=922
`

Comment: it seems you have avoided the previous error. your date time conversion is working properly. Please check once the table in which you are inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that *SURVEY.SURV_STARTDATE* and *SURVEY.S_ENDDATE* fields are typeof DATE. When you put your string type date values among quotation marks, the oraclient tries to insert them as string instead of datetime.

Try to remove those aphostrophes, like: 
*insert into SURVEY(SURV_ID,SURV_NAME,SURV_STARTDATE,S_ENDDATE) 
values('" + maxVal + "','" + SURV_NAME + "'," + SURV_STARTDATE + "," + S_ENDDATE + ")*

Answer (score 0):

First change your class:

```
public void InsertSurvey(string SURV_NAME, DateTime SURV_STARTDATE, DateTime S_ENDDA
```

to

```
public void InsertSurvey(string SURV_NAME, string SURV_STARTDATE, string S_ENDDATE)
```

You can use to_date() funciton:

```
insert into SURVEY(SURV_ID,SURV_NAME,SURV_STARTDATE,S_ENDDATE) 
values
('" + maxVal + 
 "', SURV_NAME + "','" +
 "', to_date('" + SURV_STARTDATE + ",''dd-mm-yyyy'),'" +
 "', to_date('" + S_ENDDATE + ",''dd-mm-yyyy'),'" + "');
```

Or you can use String.Format() from asp.net:

```
string startDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", txtSURV_STARTDATE.Text);
string endDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", txtS_ENDDATE.Text);
```